# Need to add if/then to a item created in a div

Tags: html, vue.js

to start off, I am not an experienced programmer at any means but I have an issues that I am trying to solve. I will try and explain it the best I can.

I have a "div" that does a v-for and sets a value in a variable that we use to display data. I need to take that variable and use like an if/then statements to change that data to something else and then display it. (I know, it probably doesn't make sense). See below.

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in flatSettings(dockets)" :key="`dockets${RELOAD_KEY}_${index}`" :data-group="item.docketId" :data-skip="item.last ? 'true' : 'false'" class="w-100 " :style="{position: 'relative', 'z-index': item.divider ? 100 : 0}" :data-label="item.settingId ? 'false' : 'true'" :data-dividerindex="item.dividerindex" :data-divider="item.divider ? 'true' : 'false'">
```

This div above looks at an API and gets the correct data and displays it in a header like so:

```
<h4 class="text-black text-center">{{item.court}} </h4>
```

I need to take that {{item.court}} and change it to something else if it equals something.

Can that be done? If I have not provided enough context and needs more information to clarify, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: What you have in your question is not vanilla HTML, please add any other relevant tags for the technologies you are using.

Comment: this can easily be done using javascript.  Are you able to use that?

Comment: Yes, we are using Javascripts. Is there one that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I had to use the v-if and v-else-if to accomplish this.

```
<h4 class="text-black text-center" v-if="item.court === '53'">John Doe</h4>
<h4 class="text-black text-center" v-else-if="item.court === '126'">Jane Doe</h4>
```